# How to config default input/output devices in ALSA config file(~/.asoundrc)?

Tags: alsa, output, input-device, microphone, speakers

I am trying to configure microphone and speaker for raspberry pi 4. I edited "~/.asoundrc" file like that:

```
pcm.!default {
   type asym
   playback.pcm "plughw:0"
   capture.pcm  "plughw:1"
}
```

But it is not working. How can I solve this problem?